# How to create separate source tree for unit tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

Its a very basic question though I can not figure out the way.

How to create a structure where

> have classes in the same package and have them in different trees,
>
> - src/main/Example.java
> - src/test/TestExample.java
>
> Is it possible to create this structure using Idea 8.0?

I was trying to create this folder structure. It turns out that it becomes different packages. 
As I intend to test functions that are visible only package level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  The mistake you probably made is you marked your `src` folder as a source root in your project settings.  Instead, you want to mark the `main` folder as the source folder and the `test` folder as your test folder.  Here's a screenshot showing where to change this:

[image]

Make sure you click on the right colors in the right folders.

But why are you using Idea 8?  You know Idea 12 is out and the community edition is free?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I did mark the wrong folder. Yea need to upgrade that.again thnx I was just wasting my time over unnecessary things!!